# Meaning of the word "around" in context

Tags: meaning

Here it goes: "He is the best teacher around." Does it mean that he is the best teacher in the world or the best in some area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> He is the best teacher around.

means

> He is the best teacher available.

So it is in local context.

Answer (score 0):

***[Around](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/around)*** here is used with the connotation of:

> in circulation, action, etc.; about:
>
> - He hasn't been around lately. The play has been around for years. When will she be up and around?  (Dictionary.com)

The best teacher you can find.